# Logical Trouble with SQL and foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

**EDITED <sup>*1</sup>**

I am a trainee as a software developer, so I haven't much experience with MySQL-Database.

I want to write a ticket for tasks, it contains detailed informations for the worker and also which worker is required.

I have a table in the database wich contains the forname, surname and the department of the worker.

The table `worker` looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+----------+------------+
| id (PK) | surname | forename | department |
+---------+---------+----------+------------+
| 1       | bar     | foo      | shop       |
+---------+---------+----------+------------+
| 2       | baz     | foo      | production |
...
```

And the table `tasks` looks like this:

```
+---------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+----
| id (PK) | task       | shop_req | shop_worker | production_req | production_worker | ...
+---------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+----
| 1       | do sth.    | yes      | 1           | yes            | 2                 | ...
+---------+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+----
| 2       | do sth.    | no       | (NULL)      | yes            | 2                 | ...
...
```

How shall I connect them together?

I tried with this SQL-Code: <sup>*1</sup>

```
ALTER TABLE tasks

ADD CONSTRAINTS FK_tasks_shop
FOREIGN KEY (shop_worker) 
REFERENCES worker(id) 
ON UPDATE RESTRICT
ON DELETE RESTRICT,

ADD CONSTRAINTS FK_tasks_production
FOREIGN KEY (production_worker) 
REFERENCES worker(id) 
ON UPDATE RESTRICT
ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

And when I call the table `tasks` with the following SQL-Code:

```
SELECT a.id, a.task, a.shop_req, CONCAT(b.surname, ', ', b.forename) AS shop_worker,
a.production_req, CONCAT(c.surname, ', ', c.forename) AS production_worker
FROM tasks AS a
JOIN worker AS b ON a.shop_worker = b.id
JOIN worker AS c ON a.production_worker = c.id
```

the result is:

```
+----+------+----------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+----
| id | task | shop_req | shop_worker | production_req | production_worker | ...
+----+------+----------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+----
```

It means the result is only the name of the columns with no rows.
**I expect the following result:**

```
+----+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+----
| id | task       | shop_req | shop_worker | production_req | production_worker | ...
+----+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+----
| 1  | do sth.    | yes      | bar, foo    | yes            | baz, foo          | ...
+----+------------+----------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+----
| 2  | do sth.    | no       | (NULL)      | yes            | baz, foo          | ...
...
```

What is wrong here? I can't find the error.
**Is there an efficient way to call the SQL-Code?**

Many thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your query is missing the `AS a` alias for `tasks` which should make the query fail. After you add that you should get one row back, but ...

Since you want to include all rows from the `tasks` table even if there are no matching rows for the `shop_worker` or `production_worker` you'll want to use `left join` instead like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.task, a.shop_req, CONCAT(b.surname, ', ', b.forename) AS shop_worker,
a.production_req, CONCAT(c.surname, ', ', c.forename) AS production_worker
FROM tasks AS a
LEFT JOIN worker AS b ON a.shop_worker = b.id
LEFT JOIN worker AS c ON a.production_worker = c.id
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44509/2)

For a good introduction to the various joins see: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

You need `left join` instead of `inner join`

```
SELECT 
a.id, 
a.task,
a.shop_req, 
CONCAT(b.surname, ', ', b.forename) AS shop_worker,
a.production_req, 
CONCAT(c.surname, ', ', c.forename) AS production_worker
FROM tasks a
left join worker b ON a.shop_worker = b.id
left join worker c ON a.production_worker = c.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much, too. But you forgot also the `AS` in your Code.

Comment: You do not need `as` without that it should work too.